# How to add a GameObject as a child of Ground Stage Plane dynamically on button touch?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, android-augmented-reality

I wish to have an interface with multiple buttons (Astronaut, Drone, Canister etc.) which then appear over the Ground Plane when the user presses a button.

I'm having a hard time making my prefabs as a child of the Ground Plane Stage dynamically. I'm also not entirely certain on the working of ContentPositioningBehavior script which seems to do it.

Can anyone please help? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you look at the API / do some research? [`var newObject = Instantiate(prefab, groundPlane.transform);`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) or [`newObject.transform.SetParent(groundPlane.transform)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetParent.html) or [`newObject.transform.parent = groundPlane.transform;`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-parent.html) ...

Comment: @derHugo, yes I did but I had a hard time understanding that it was the transform component was the one that we needed.
My apologies, I'm a complete beginner at this. 
But thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is an overload for `Instantiate()`, which is

```
Instantiate(Object object, Transform parent)
```

In order for instantiated gameObjects to have ground plane as a parent, you can just pass it as `parent` parameter. Like:

```cs
[SerializeField]
private Transform groundPlane; // Drag ground plane to this in inspector.

private void OnClickAstronautButton()
{
    Instanitiate(astroPrefab, groundPlane);
}

...
```

Also, there is `Transform.parent` field. You can assign to this field, like

```cs
astronaut.transform.parent = groundPlane;
```